# Installing Ubuntu on Acer V-3-574G

Tags: acer

I just bought myself a Acer V3-574G with core i7 and Nvidia Geforce 940m 2gb vga with 12gb Ram with factory installed Win-10. I am having problem installing any linux distro on it even after I dissable UEFI. Coluld somebody please tell me how I could install linux on this computer.

Thank you

Nick.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly the problem you are encountering?

Comment: It starts with the DVD or even USB like normal GRUB screen with the menu, and when I choose try without installing or even installing it goes to a blank black screen and tells me " 0.002855 ACPI: unable to load the system description tables. " and nothing happens afterwords.

Comment: UEFI to Legacy mode in Boot Mode will fix this problem

Comment: I have disabled UEFI and loaded on Legacy and I have been getting the same message. I tried with Ubuntu 15.10,Mint 17, New Ultimate and Gparten and it was all the same issue....

Comment: Is it because of my VGA?

Answer (score 2):

With Acer it could be a BIOS problem. Go look at Acer support pages if there is an BIOS update for your (EXACT) model of computer. If yes, follow the instructions there to install it. I had to do it with Lenovo. In my case the BIOS update was only possible in Windows.

Comment: Ok dude, I will try and will let you know......  Thank you so much for your help.......

Comment: Hey mate, I updated the bios and tried installing, and it worked...... Thank you very much for that info. I usually try all possible way but this I did not think cos of the new Laptop. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem. I had some problems with BIOS too (on Lenovo G50).